# Eventarc API Firestore Triggers in european region not working?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, cloud, google-cloud-run, event-arc

#### What I want to achieve

I am trying to setup an Eventarc trigger. A specific Firestore action (deletion of a document) should trigger a Cloud Run service instance.

#### My problem

The service should be provided in europe but...

**Eventarc** is only supported in the following regions:

- europe-north1
- europe-west1
- europe-west4

(https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/locations#europe)

**Firestore** is only supported in the following regions:

- europe-west2
- europe-west3
- europe-west6
- europe-central12

(https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations)

When I tried setting up the trigger on the Cloud Run Service, it prompted me to select a region from where (i.e. the region) the trigger should originate and receive events from. My Firestore region is set to europe-west3. Since Eventarc is not supported in this region I was trying to find our if I can get Firestore into a supported Eventarc region in Europe but there is literally none. Does that theoretically mean that Eventarc does not support Firestore in Europe at all?

[There is the option to select all regions but I assume that this just means receiving events from all the supported regions, right?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuXRc.png)

Is there any way I can get this working or any official plans from Google about when to support this?

Answer (score 1):

since the region is not supported by Eventarc right now, your only option is to create a global trigger. As you mentioned, this will trigger will get events from all regions. Eventarc will be adding new regions soon but I don't have details on what exact regions.